# delete alternate lines in a csv file libreoffice calc

Tags: csv, libreoffice-calc

I have a csv file and I need to delete all even lines (example: line 2, line 4, line 6 ecc.). They are over 7000. It's possible to do with a single command or function in Libreoffice Calc?

Comment: No, it's not necessary

Comment: You can do `awk 'NR % 2 != 0' input.csv >> output.csv`

Comment: As i see, awk is a Linux command. I need to do it in Windows 10

Comment: Windows 10 now has [Bash on Ubuntu on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/about) with `awk`.  However, this can easily be done with LO Calc as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, if the data is in column A, then enter this formula in B1 and fill down.

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()*2-1;1))
```

[image: odd rows only]

Answer (score 1):

Excellent A (as usual) from @JimK but might not adapt too well if the rows to be deleted contain data in many columns. So though not a *single command or function* (more a process that should at least achieve the result, if not in the preferred way):

Fill as much of a (spare) column as required with:

```
=ISODD(ROW())
```

then filter to select `FALSE`s and delete these rows. The helper column may then also be deleted.